# Characters that SQL doesn't use

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a php class that executes queries for me when I pass in a query and multiple parameters to use in the query. In the query string, instead of using $user,$password,etc, I would like to reference the additional parameters I pass in, such as

```
select * from info where user_id = &param1
```

However, I do not want to use any character significant in a SQL statement for obvious reasons. What character should I go with to denote a query parameter in my query string?

Comment: Unsure, but `?` might be something. At least I believe I've seen it in other database query helper frameworks in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of what Gordon said, you should beware of the apostrophe `'` as well. You have to double it if you really want to write it.

`"John O'Brien"` becomes `"John O''Brien"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

There are a variety of characters that either are not used or are rarely used in MySQL:  '#', '!',, '~', and '^' for instance.

However, I might recommend that you do something with a character at the *beginning* and *end* of the parameter value.  For instance, '{' and '}'.

This is based on my experience of putting parameters into queries.  If you are planning on using direct string replace, the '@X' and '@XX' might interfere with each other -- if you replace the first one before the second.  With delimited names like '{X}' and '{XX}', this doesn't happen.

Of course, you might have a more sophisticate parser than simply replacing strings (and that is a good idea because anything -- pretty much -- can appear in a string constant).  If so, then this consideration might not be an issue.

Comment: @ is used for scalar variables and % is used pretty often in wildcard searches. other ones look promising.